# Why dragger not appear to move rows in UITableView?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I try to move rows in `tableView`, so I set:

```
tableView.setEditing(true, animated: true)
```

But dragger does not appear on the right side, only the red negative removes signs on the left.

Why?

I have implemented `canMoveRowAtIndexPath` method:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {

    return true
}
```

[image]

Comment: If it's a custom cell check the content of your cell, whether it's overlapping that portion or not

Comment: It is a `Right Detail` cell, so it show is not overlapping theoretically, but see pic above

Comment: Check the value of `showsReorderControl` for the UITableViewCell.

Comment: Did you implement the other delegate methods related to cell moving?

Comment: `showsReorderControl` was off, I turned on, but does not help, no other method is implemented

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were two missing thing

1) need `showsReorderControl`

2) need to define / implement `moveRowAtIndexPath`, even before drag event.